# Using Mako with Pyramid causes an error

Tags: python, pylons, mako, pyramid

When trying to use Mako with the Pyramid framework, by going into the development.ini file, and adding the line

```
mako.directories = TestProject:templates
```

in:

```
[app:TestProject]
```

and then creating a simple html file called template.mako in the templates subdirectory I get an:

```
ImportError: No module named TestProject
```

But I fail to understand why this is happening after the above steps. Why are those steps generating an importError?

More detials of the error:

```
URL: http://localhost:6543/
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\weberror-0.10.3-py2.7.egg\\weberror\\evalexception.py', line 431 in respond
app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\router.py', line 158 in __call__
response = view_callable(context, request)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\config.py', line 2839 in _rendered_view
context)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\renderers.py', line 294 in render_view
request=request)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\renderers.py', line 322 in render_to_response
result = self.render(value, system_values, request=request)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\renderers.py', line 298 in render
renderer = self.renderer
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\decorator.py', line 17 in __get__
val = self.wrapped(inst)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\renderers.py', line 280 in renderer
return factory(self)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\mako_templating.py', line 77 in renderer_factory
directories = [ abspath_from_asset_spec(d) for d in directories ]
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\pyramid-1.0-py2.7.egg\\pyramid\\asset.py', line 207 in abspath_from_asset_spec
return pkg_resources.resource_filename(pname, filename)
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88124-py2.7.egg\\pkg_resources.py', line 881 in resource_filename
File 'C:\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88124-py2.7.egg\\pkg_resources.py', line 201 in get_provider
ImportError: No module named TestProject
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As summary:

Edit the file `development.ini` and add in the section `[app:MyProject]`:

> mako.directories = myproject:templates

Now we can open the file `/MyProject/myproject/__init__.py` and add a line like:

> config.add_route('foo', '/foo', view='myproject.views.foo', view_renderer='foo.mako')

This will render the template located in:
`/MyProject/myproject/templates/foo.mako`

---

Note: **MyProject** and **myproject** are the name of YOUR project. Respect the case.

Remember to do the same configuration in `production.ini` file!

**Edit**:I see in the 1.3a1 version of pyramid (2011-12-09) Changelog in the Features section:

> A mako.directories setting is no longer required to use Mako templates
>   Rationale: Mako template renderers can be specified using an absolute
>   asset spec. An entire application can be written with such
>   asset specs, requiring no ordered lookup path.

Comment: It appears that for pyramid 1.3, the `mako.directories = myproject:templates` setting goes under `[app:main]`, not `[app:MyProject]`

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the mako.templates specifiction is in the format of package:directory. Therefore you must have a package called, in your case, "TestProject".

You may have a package for your project, but it's apparently not called "TestProject".

Comment: Ah yes, thank you in my case the package name was called testproject and not TestProject.